# How can I make dpkg-buildpackage stop after running configure?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

**Introduction**

I have a source package (downloaded with `apt source ...`) which I'd like to explore using [rtags](https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags) in a code editor.
The standard way of doing this is to dry-run the makefile produced by the build system feeding it to `rtags` so that it could use those commands for (re)building its contextual source code navigation and auto-completion databases.

**Problem**

Normally, I would just `autogen`/`autoconf`/`configure` to obtain a makefile and then dry-run the build with `make -nk`.

However, since I'm working with a Debian  package, I need to use the Debian-specific configuration commands with `dpkg-buildpackage` or `dpkg-source` in order for the source code navigation to reflect the same build options that were used in the official builds.

I looked through `buildpackage`'s man page but couldn't find any options that would stop the build after the `./configure` step, before any actual build commands are executed. While it *does* have the `--build=source`(`-S`) option, it doesn't do what I want: it applies Ubuntu-specific patches and then stops *before* running `automake`/`configure`. This is unacceptable, since I want the `automake`/`configure` step to be executed as well.

**Question**

How can I make `dpkg-buildpackage` stop AFTER running `autogen`/`automake`/`configure` but BEFORE running `make`?

The suggested approach should work for the `dnsutils` source package.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the `dpkg-buildpackage` manpage, you'll see that it doesn't distinguish between a `configure` step and a `make` step  - as far it is concerned, there's a `build` step and a `binary` step. While `./configure; make; make install` is very common, it's not sanctified as the one true build method by `dpkg-buildpackage`; it's left to `debian/rules` to invoke appropriate actions as needed.

In the specific case of `dnsutils`, or rather, `bind`, `debian/rules` seems to be highly manual (even though it invokes a number of debhelper utilities, it doesn't rely on debhelper's automation). So here, the simplest way is to take advantage of the targets in `debian/rules`:

```
$ debian/rules stamps/configure
dh_testdir
if [ ! -d autoreconf-bck ]; then \
    mkdir autoreconf-bck; \
    cp -pr config.h.in configure libtool.m4 ltmain.sh autoreconf-bck; \
fi
cp -r bin/named bin/named-pkcs11
cp -r bin/dnssec bin/dnssec-pkcs11
cp -r lib/isc lib/isc-pkcs11
cp -r lib/dns lib/dns-pkcs11
patch -p1 < debian/patches/extra-add_native_pkcs11.diff
patching file bin/dnssec-pkcs11/Makefile.in
patching file bin/named-pkcs11/Makefile.in
...
========================================================================
Configuration summary:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Optional features enabled:
    Multiprocessing support (--enable-threads)
    GeoIP access control (--with-geoip)
    GSS-API (--with-gssapi)
    Native PKCS#11/Cryptoki support (--enable-native-pkcs11)
        Provider library: ${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so
    GOST algorithm support (encoding: raw) (--with-gost)
    ECDSA algorithm support (--with-ecdsa)
    AAAA filtering (--enable-filter-aaaa)
    Print backtrace on crash (--enable-backtrace)
    Use symbol table for backtrace, named only (--enable-symtable)
    Use GNU libtool (--with-libtool)
    Dynamically loadable zone (DLZ) drivers:
        None

Features disabled or unavailable on this platform:
    Large-system tuning (--with-tuning)
    Recursive fetch limits for DoS attack mitigation (--enable-fetchlimit)
    Source Identity Token support (--enable-sit)
    Allow 'fixed' rrset-order (--enable-fixed-rrset)
    OpenSSL cryptography/DNSSEC (--with-openssl)
    Use libseccomp system call filtering (--enable-seccomp)
    Very verbose query trace logging (--enable-querytrace)
    Automated Testing Framework (--with-atf)
    JSON statistics (--with-libjson)

Unrecognized options:
    --enable-rrl
========================================================================
touch stamps/configure
```

If it were using debhelper's `dh_auto_configure`, another way would have been to override `dh_auto_configure` in `debian/rules` to fail the build process after it.

---

In general, `dpkg-buildpackage` doesn't know anything about `configure`, and so has no way to stop there.